# tkinter canvas Dimensionado de la presentación inicial

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

En el siguiente programa, adaptación de un [ejemplo del foro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731784/tkinter-self.canvas-scrollbar-with-grid), me gustaria que cuando se ejecuta se presentase, inicialmente, con el tamaño horizontal suficiente para ver la etiqueta completa, y no tener que hacer scroll horizontal.

Leo que todos los widgets de adaptan, en tamaño, para contener a sus widgets dependientes, pero aquí no encuentro la razón de que no se haga así.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as font

muestra_low = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
muestra_up =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

class MyApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.configure(bg="Light Blue", bd=3, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        # Create a frame for the self.canvas and scrollbar(s).
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add a self.canvas in that frame.
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame2, bg="Yellow")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        frame2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Permite crecer self.canvas horizontalmente
        frame2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the self.canvas.
        vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

        # Create a horizontal scrollbar linked to the self.canvas.
        hsbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        hsbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsbar.set)

        # Create a frame on the self.canvas to contain the labels.
        labels_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="Red", bd=2)

        ###############################

        self.portLabela = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= "Courrier", font="Courrier")
        self.portLabela.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="w")

        self.portLabelb = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= muestra_low, font="Courrier")
        self.portLabelb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="w")

        self.portLabelb = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= muestra_up, font="Courrier")
        self.portLabelb.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky="w")
        ###############################

        # Create self.canvas window to hold the labels_frame.
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=labels_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

        labels_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)  # Get bounding box of self.canvas with Labels.

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Es decir, se presenta asi:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUsL9.png]

cuando me gustaria que la presentación inicial fuese esta:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2T0a.png]

¿Donde debo de tocar o que estoy omitiendo?

Nota: los colores están forzados para ser capaz de distinguir cada frame. Estoy aprendiendo :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El widget Canvas no modifica su tamaño para adaptarse a su contenido, si quieres que de inicio tenga el tamaño mínimo para contener al item, puedes modificar su ancho usando la información proporcionada por `bbox(tk.ALL)`, una vez agregados los items en el inicializador:

```
bbox = self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)
self.canvas.config(width=bbox[2] - bbox[0])
```

El código completo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as font

muestra_low = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
muestra_up =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

class MyApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.configure(bg="Light Blue", bd=3, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        # Create a frame for the self.canvas and scrollbar(s).
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add a self.canvas in that frame.
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame2, bg="Yellow")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        frame2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Permite crecer self.canvas horizontalmente
        frame2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the self.canvas.
        vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

        # Create a horizontal scrollbar linked to the self.canvas.
        hsbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        hsbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsbar.set)

        # Create a frame on the self.canvas to contain the labels.
        labels_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="Red", bd=2)

        ###############################

        self.portLabela = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= "Courrier", font="Courrier")
        self.portLabela.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="w")

        self.portLabelb = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= muestra_low, font="Courrier")
        self.portLabelb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="w")

        self.portLabelb = tk.Label(labels_frame, text= muestra_up, font="Courrier")
        self.portLabelb.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky="w")
        ###############################

        # Create self.canvas window to hold the labels_frame.
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=labels_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

        labels_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)  # Get bounding box of self.canvas with Labels.
        self.canvas.config(width=bbox[2] - bbox[0])

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfecto. Una pregunta más, si es posible. ¿En base a que delimita Tkinter las dimensiones del canvas por defecto?

Comment: Hola Chemag, pues es una buena pregunta. Ahora mismo no sabría decirte y la documentación de TCL/Tk no menciona nada al respecto. He probado por curiosidad y en mi caso el canvas tiene siempre (independientemente de que esté vacío o no o del administrador de geometría usado) 506x355 supongo que diferirá en base a características del sistema como tamaño/resolución de pantalla), voy a ver si investigo y encuentro algo...

Comment: Tus consejos y sugerencias me están siendo muy útiles. Los estoy aplicando en ejemplos del foro, y me siento bastante seguro